# Library for processing HTML

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a Java - (Android) library that is able to parse HTML this way:

Imagine that I obtain a String with the content of an HTML page, I'd like to process it like Javascript would do.

Imagine:

```
    String HtmlPage = "<html>....</html>";
    HTMLElement[] elements = MagicLibrary.getElementsByClassName("className");
```

Not sure if there is a specific library for this one. If not, I will try implementing it myself, but I couldn't find an answer through my initial search.

I'm sorry that I couldn't explain better in English.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), it is configurable and has pretty good documentation.

Here's an [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) of the way it works:

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
// "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

Moreover, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/) are some get-to-know examples with the library.
So, after getting a basic understanding and if in the need of some additional examples, according to your case (Android), refer to the following ones:

- http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html
- http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks alot i was looking for something like this! :·)

Comment: So, if it's the solution for you, you should also accept this answer (by marking the tick symbol, left for its votes count), for any future reference.

Comment: Yea, i was waiting for it to let me do it (3mins) :·). Thanks again.